# scroll in DrawerLayout

Tags: android, scrollview, android-scrollview, drawerlayout

My slide menu works perfect but when I want to scroll in slide menu I can't. I have enough items in  list view to scroll. How to scroll in DrawerLayout?
The scroll bar shows but I cant do anything. Should I add it programmatically?

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <!-- Framelayout to display Fragments -->
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/frame_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    </ScrollView>
    <!-- Listview to display slider menu -->
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list_slidermenu"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="@color/list_divider"
        android:dividerHeight="1dp"
        android:listSelector="@drawable/list_selector"
        android:background="@color/list_background"
     />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_pick"
            android:layout_width="90dp"
            android:layout_height="55dp"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:text="pick" />
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/sticker"
            android:layout_width="90dp"
            android:layout_height="55dp"
            android:text="add sticker"
            android:layout_below="@+id/paint_view"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/save"
            android:layout_width="90dp"
            android:layout_height="55dp"
            android:text="save"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
    <in.wptrafficanalyzer.graphicspickimageviewcanvas.PaintView
        android:id="@+id/paint_view"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_above="@id/btn_pick" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: First remove scroll view from layout, second you r going on wrong track find example of drawer layout understand first then try your self

Comment: whats the purpose of scroll view here ?

Comment: List view inside scrollview?

Comment: remove scroll view, the listview has scrolling feature.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to put your other widgets into the frame layout, try this,

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/frame_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_pick"
            android:layout_width="90dp"
            android:layout_height="55dp"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:text="pick" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/sticker"
            android:layout_width="90dp"
            android:layout_height="55dp"
            android:text="add sticker"
            android:layout_below="@+id/paint_view"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/save"
            android:layout_width="90dp"
            android:layout_height="55dp"
            android:text="save"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
        <in.wptrafficanalyzer.graphicspickimageviewcanvas.PaintView
            android:id="@+id/paint_view"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_above="@id/btn_pick" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</FrameLayout>

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/list_slidermenu"
    android:layout_width="240dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
    android:divider="@color/list_divider"
    android:dividerHeight="1dp"
    android:listSelector="@drawable/list_selector"
    android:background="@color/list_background"
 />
```